# java.io.FileNotFoundException in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to run the [Code Generator](https://github.com/shenkunlin/code-template) in intellij

But I am getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException: xxx\target\classes\template\xxx does not exist` for all the files under the template folder.

I have no idea how the `\target` file works, but I did check that all the files that were claimed to be missing by the compiler are there in the `\target` folder.

Also,  in one of the files `\TemplateBuilder.java`:

They import a package `javafx.scene.control.Tab`. When I first ran the project, it returned that javac 8 was used to compile java sources and this package does not exist. Then I set language level to 9, where it returned release version 5 not supported. So i had to delete the import of `javafx.scene.control.Tab` which does not seem to be used anywhere in the code. But now it returns the `FileNotFoundException`.

update:

The full error message reads:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\xxx\First%Project\code-template-master\target\classes\template\pojo does not exist`

This looks wired, since my folder's name is actually and `\First Project` and I think the file should be `pojo.java`

Comment: Why did you change the language level to 9 and what was the issue with javac 8?

Comment: I searched online and got the impression that javafx.scene.control.java is not supported for java versions under 9.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you actually use the correct paths, so that this isn't your actual problem.
The following returns true if the file could be found :

```
Files.exists(Paths.get(pathString))
```

Make sure you use the relative path to your project root.

Comment: I cannot find the file according to the path given in the error message, and I noticed something wired. Please see my update. But I do not actually know which part of the program is quoting the path of those files thus unable to fix this, if that is the problem.

Comment: IDK what to learn from your update, but really make sure you use paths right. Learn about absolute/relative paths and tests if you can ready in a textfile you wrote yourself for example. If you verified you can do this, you at least know that the problem doesn't lie there.